# Set object properties more efficiently

Tags: java, object, oop, groovy

Is there a way to set object properties more efficiently than this if I have more than 50 properties?

```
    object.setProperty1(value1);
    object.setProperty2(value2);
    object.setProperty3(value3);
    object.setProperty4(value4);
    object.setProperty5(value5);
              .
              .
              .
```

Comment: like using a constructor/ builder? 50 properties sound like a lot to put inside a constructor though. do you need to update the properties at all after the object was created? and do you need to update all of them at once all of the time?

Comment: You could use a loop and the ``java.lang.reflect`` package.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to use the constructor, you could use the builder pattern.
The final result would look something like this:

```
Object.getBuilder()
    .property1(a)
    .property2(b)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Bean mapping frameworks like MapStruct, which allow to map fields between pojo's automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spring BeanUtils` to handle it